# How to set onClickListener on RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I have made a card view which loads data from the internet and displays it. I have a JSONParser class to parse the json data. Then, I store the data in an arraylist of ListItem type. But, I am not able to use the onCliclListener.

Here is the JSONParser.java File:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{

    Context c;
    String jsonData;
    RecyclerView rv;
    private final Context context=null;

    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ages=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> addresses=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> bgs=new ArrayList<>();

    List<ListItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


    public JSONParser(Context c, String jsonData, RecyclerView rv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
        this.rv = rv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Parse JSON");
        pd.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return parse();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isParsed) {
        super.onPostExecute(isParsed);

        pd.dismiss();
        if(isParsed)
        {
            //BIND
            MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(c,names,ages,addresses,bgs);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unable To Parse,Check Your Log output", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private Boolean parse()
    {
        try
        {
            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
            JSONObject jo;

            names.clear();
            ages.clear();
            addresses.clear();
            bgs.clear();

            for (int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
            {
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

                List<ListItem> ldata = new ArrayList<>();
                ListItem item = new ListItem();

                String name=jo.getString("name");
                String age=jo.getString("mob");
                String address=jo.getString("add");
                String bg=jo.getString("bg");

                names.add(name);
                ages.add(age);
                addresses.add(address);
                bgs.add(bg);

                item.setName(name);
                item.setAge(age);
                item.setAddress(address);
                item.setBg(bg);

                ldata.add(item);

                setData(ldata);
            }

            return true;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setData(List<ListItem> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<ListItem> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Here is the MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.ItemClickCallback {

    String jsonURL="http://projectred.in/phploginwebservice/index.php?tag=reqjson&cur=JAIPUR";
    RecyclerView rv;
    ArrayList listData;
    JSONParser jsonParser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listData = (ArrayList) jsonParser.getData();

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONDownloader(MainActivity.this,jsonURL, rv).execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int p) {
        ListItem item = (ListItem) listData.get(p);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Title: " + item.getName() + "\nSubtitle :" + item.getAge()+ "\nAddress :" + item.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSecondaryIconClick(int p) {

    }
}
```

This is my adapter java code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<String> names;
    ArrayList<String> ages;
    ArrayList<String> addresses;
    ArrayList<String> bgs;


    private ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback;

    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> ages, ArrayList<String> addresses, ArrayList<String> bgs) {
        this.c = c;
        this.names = names;
        this.ages = ages;
        this.addresses = addresses;
        this.bgs = bgs;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    public interface ItemClickCallback {
        void onItemClick(int p);

        void onSecondaryIconClick(int p);
    }

    public void setItemClickCallback(final ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
        this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //BIND
        holder.nameTxt.setText(names.get(position));
        holder.ageTxt.setText(ages.get(position));
        holder.addTxt.setText(addresses.get(position));
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("AP")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.apr);
        }
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("AN")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.anr);
        }
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("BP")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bpr);
        }
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("BN")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bnr);
        }
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("ABP")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.abpr);
        }
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("ABN")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.abnr);
        }
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("OP")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.opr);
        }
        if (bgs.get(position).toString().equals("ON")) {
            holder.bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.onr);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return names.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView nameTxt, ageTxt, addTxt;
        ImageView bg;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView101);
            ageTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView887);
            addTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView77);
            bg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView83);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.cont_item_root) {
                itemClickCallback.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            } else {
                itemClickCallback.onSecondaryIconClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is showing a null pointer exception.

This is my LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.tutorials.hp.jsonrecyclerview.m_JSON.JSONParser.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.tutorials.hp.jsonrecyclerview.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                                       at com.tutorials.hp.jsonrecyclerview.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                                       at com.tutorials.hp.jsonrecyclerview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4098) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: please share your adapter java code

Comment: Nullpointer exception where? Post your logcat

Comment: done @TiagoOliveira

Comment: im checking if something is wrong i just implemented the same thing on my app 10min ago

Comment: okay @TiagoOliveira

Comment: i tought your problem was on the onclicklistener, i saw your log, you are calling `jsonParser.getData()` without initializing `jsonParser`

Comment: You are not initializing `JSONParser` in your main activity. That's why it is showing null printer exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: do I make a blank Constructor in the JSONParser.java file ? @TiagoOliveira

Comment: Yes, you can overload the class constructor method with one that takes no arguments.

Comment: yes but you cant use jasonparser right away you have to wait until the asyc finishes, will update my awnser

Comment: I also don't see you referencing your `setItemClickCallback` interface in your Activity. It's implemented, but it needs to be called in your `onCreate` to let the interface know that your Activity is listening. Also, in your FAB's onClick method, `MainActivity.this,jsonURL` can just be `jsonURL` since it's a class member.

Comment: how exaclty can I do this ? @mwieczorek

Comment: @ChayanDashora please avoid writing "Please help me" in the question. People here are Stack Overflow are here to help you, so writing this is just annoying.

Comment: @TiagoOliveira nothing is happening !

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize JsonParser

```
jsonParser = new JsonParser(c, jsonData, rv);
listData = (ArrayList) jsonParser.getData();
```

However you can't call `jsonParser.getData` right away you need to wait until the asynctask finishes.

```
public class JSONParser {
ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> ages=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> addresses=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> bgs=new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<ListItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

public JSONParser(final Context c, final String jsonData, final RecyclerView rv, final OnFinishListener onFinishListener) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
            pd.setTitle("Parse JSON");
            pd.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
                JSONObject jo;

                names.clear();
                ages.clear();
                addresses.clear();
                bgs.clear();

                for (int i=0;i<ja.length();i++) {
                    jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

                    ArrayList<ListItem> ldata = new ArrayList<>();
                    ListItem item = new ListItem();

                    String name=jo.getString("name");
                    String age=jo.getString("mob");
                    String address=jo.getString("add");
                    String bg=jo.getString("bg");

                    names.add(name);
                    ages.add(age);
                    addresses.add(address);
                    bgs.add(bg);

                    item.setName(name);
                    item.setAge(age);
                    item.setAddress(address);
                    item.setBg(bg);

                    ldata.add(item);

                    setData(ldata);
                }

                return true;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isParsed) {
            super.onPostExecute(isParsed);

            pd.dismiss();
            if(isParsed) {
                //BIND
                MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(c,names,ages,addresses,bgs);
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                onFinishListener.finished(data);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Unable To Parse,Check Your Log output", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}




public void setData(ArrayList<ListItem> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public ArrayList<ListItem> getData() {
    return data;
}

public interface OnFinishListener{
    void finished(ArrayList<ListItem> data);
}
}
```

In your **MainActivity.java**

```
jsonParser = new JsonParser(c, jsonData, rv,new JSONParser.OnFinishListener() {
        @Override
        public void finished(ArrayList<ListItem> data) {
            listData = data;
        }
    });
```

This should work, if i missed something let me know.

Just like NoobGeek said you need to setOnclickLiestenr to your views, if you don't set any onclicklister you wont be able to get listen for clicks for example,

```
  //nameTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
  //ageTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
  //addTxt.setOnClickListener(this);

  //i don't see the cont_item_root anywhere 

  //bg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView83);
  bg.setOnClickListener(this);

  ...
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView83) { //maybe this?
            itemClickCallback.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing is happening after clicking the card item !

Comment: you have more then one problem with your code please give me me some time to check

Comment: It says onfinishlistener is not public in JSONParser..shall I make it public ?

Comment: well I did that, and it is showing null pointer exception again !

Comment: where? on the jsonparser? or on the interface?

Comment: in the jsonparser

Comment: i updated my question i don't see any reson for this not to work give it a try

Comment: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.tutorials.hp.jsonrecyclerview.m_JSON.JSONParser$OnFinishListener.finished()' on a null object reference

Comment: yhe the interface is null let me check what i did wrong give me a monument

Comment: i have to leave but i will try to fix this when i come back home, in the meantime you can make a method in your `Activity`  when you call setData instead of calling the method in your jsonparse call the methon on the activity class you do something like this `Activity.setData(data)` this is not that great but it will work

Comment: @ChayanDashora  Do you know that there is more then one timezone? one comment saying that is not working is enought, if i didn't respond was because i was sleeping, where exaclty are you exactly the`NullPointerException` ? give me an exemple of the json string that you are passing